# How does I-Cal calculate time?

Tags: php, email, icalendar

I'm taking the time in UTC, and then conveting the time into a specific timezone's time to send it as a calender invite,

Consider a date function such as,

```
$date = new DateTime('2012-07-17 09:00:00 +00'); //UTC
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Chicago'));

echo $start_time=$date->format('H:i:s'); // echoes 04:00:00; //
```

But passing the same time in outlook such as,

```
$ical .= "DTSTART:".$start."T".$start_time."\r\n";
```

Does not give a time which is 9:00 AM in America, instead the calender time is set as some other time(9:30 am). 
What can I do to solve this issue?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: in my ical files i format DTSTART like this: `DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20170922T200000` no problems so far with it. Here you find a documentation http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/dateTime.html

Answer (score 0):

Looking at some examples [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar), it looks like it uses the format `Ymd`<kbd>T</kbd>`His`<kbd>Z</kbd>, with `T` and `Z` being literal.

So you want to pass something like:

```
$ical .= "DTSTART:".$date->format('Ymd\THis\Z')."\r\n";
```

Comment: Nope this also triggers the same way..If you see Asia/Kolkata ; UTC for 9:00:00 is 090000 and IST for this is returned as 143000 but when I pass 1430000 to the ical, it shows the invite as 8PM instead of 9AM. Not sure of what I'm missing here

Comment: You should be passing in the UTC time for the event. You're passing IST as if it were UTC, which doubles the error (you ended up 11 hours ahead, which is double the 5.5 hour offset)

Comment: Thank you. You are right. Also somewhere internally in windows, outlook the calculation is already taking place..so offsets must be subtracted.